# Suite nlapiSearchRecord adding filters via UI and code

Tags: suitescript

is it possible to add filters in both the UI and a suitescript 1 function and use them in combination?

Im doing a search for items and would like to limit the search results by the criteria set in the UI but also add parameters into the suitescript code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `nlobjSearch.addFilter(newFilter);` after loading the search object.